# Watcher in the wind-side mission

Tags: batman-arkham-city

In batman arkham city, the side mission "Watcher in the Wind" starts after the first mission is completed. If someone was to leave the mission, not talk to the stranger and come back after the game is completed, can you still find Azriel and start the mission?